# The meaning of " sinthry-go has disconceited me,"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

> ‘Whin I was Corp’ril—I was rejuced aftherwards—but, as I say, whin I was Corp’ril, I was the divil av a man.’
>
> He was silent for nearly a minute, while his mind rummaged among old memories and his eye glowed. He bit upon the pipe-stem and charged into his tale.
>
> ‘Eyah! They was great times. I’m ould now. Me hide’s wore off in patches; **sinthry-go has disconceited me,**

This is from ["The Solid Muldoon"](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-solid-muldoon.htm) by Rudyard Kipling.

I don't understand the meaning of

> sinthry-go has disconceited me

'sinthry-go' means 'sentry-go'?

Comment: Mulvaney's strange speech is, of course, Kipling's attempt to reproduce the character's strong Irish accent.

Answer (score 1):

sentry-go means the duty of being a sentry, and "conceit" means excessive pride on oneself, so I think "disconceited" in this case means the duty of being a sentry has removed his pride.